# How to sort a List<Position> to be from closest to furthest? Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, localization, xamarin.forms, position, compare

I'm looking for a plugin to sort a list of Positions (every position includes latitude and longitude) from the closest to my current position to the furthest, but I couldn't find anything that may be helpful yet.

Comment: Some simple trig will work to get the distance between two locations (lat/long pairs), apply this within a `IComparer` in your List.Sort(...) method...

Comment: It worked, thank you SushiHangover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do properly, see the equations on this page http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
Then do as SushiHangover says on the result